# Problem on error code ORA-12154 resolving Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

I am unable to resolve this error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>sqlplus dunya/tiger@ORADATA

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sun Feb 2 13:46:10 2018
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

In the database:

```
SQL> select database_name from v$database;

DATABASE_NAME
----------------------------------------------------
ORADATA

SQL> select instance_name from v$instance;

INSTANCE_NAME
----------------
oradata
```

tnsnames.ora:

```
ORADATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=himanshu-PC)(PORT=1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = oradata)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = himanshu-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORADATA)
      (ORACLE_HOME = G:\app\himanshu\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = oradata)
    )
  )
```

sqlnet.ora:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

Comment: If `@ORADATA` isn't being recognised then either it doesn't match your `tnsnames.ora` entry, or maybe more likely given what you've posted, that file is in the wrong place and isn't being referenced at all. Do you have `$TNS_ADMIN` set to point to the directory the file is in? And how are you connecting when you run the queries you showed?